# Select status wise rows from duplicate rows and distinct rows from table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need some help in SQL Server

I have a number of table rows like below.

```
ID   Name          status  
1    viral/AHD     Yes  
2    viral/AHD     No  
3    joe/US        Yes  
4    thomas/IND    Yes   
5    jack/IND      No
```

Now I want to select those rows which are distinct in `Name` column, that is the 3rd, 4th, 5th and those rows which are duplicate in `Name` but `status` is `Yes`..

So my final answer would be like this:

```
ID   Name          Status  
1    viral/AHD     Yes  
3    joe/US        Yes  
4    thomas/IND    Yes  
5    jack/IND      No
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using sql 2005+. Then this might help:

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name 
                     ORDER BY 
                    (CASE WHEN status='Yes' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)) AS RowNbr,
        Table1.*
    FROM
        Table1
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    CTE
WHERE
    CTE.RowNbr=1
```

**EDIT**

Or even simpler. Like this:

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name 
                    ORDER BY status DESC) AS RowNbr,
        Table1.*
    FROM
        Table1
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    CTE
WHERE
    CTE.RowNbr=1
```

Useful references:

- [OVER Clause (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)
- [WITH common_table_expression (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Arion..that work great..i got the my answer..but little bit confuse.. what is PARTITION/;WITH CTE ?? and how to use it?

Comment: @viral : I added some useful links for you to read up on. No problem. Glad to help:P